# How to make a roblox authentication v2 app in python

Tags: python, authentication, web, roblox

i want to make a roblox login page for my roblox verification app, but im not sure how to actually implement the [roblox authentication v2 api](https://auth.roblox.com/docs/index.html?urls.primaryName=Authentication%20Api%20v2) in my python app, any help would be very appreciated, ive been trying to do this for years so yeah any help would be really appreciated.